# Finding $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} \frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}$

Tags: limits, logarithms

I am trying to find the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the function below:

$$f(n) = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} \frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}$$

The textbook only gives me an answer but I don't know how it got to it.
I got confused with the factorials within logs.

**Edit:** I understand that this could be expanded to:

$$f(n) = \frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n)} \frac{\ln(n) + \ln(n-1) + ...}{\ln(n+1) + \ln(n) + \ln(n-1) + ...}$$

I'm confused which terms get reduced to zero as $n \to \infty$ or how to group them.

Comment: The log of a product is the sum of the logs.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks. I understand the log rule but i don't know how it converges.

Comment: You said you were confused with the factorials, get rid of them.

Comment: My apologies I don't think I expressed my issue well enough.

Comment: None of the solutions below provides a full account of the crucial parts of the proof that is understandable to the OP's level assumed to be a less than or equal of a junior at a university regrettably.

Comment: @DeepSea Thanks for the help. Yep. I'm doing first year calculus. The context of the question was to find the radius of convergence of a series using the ratio test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
\begin{align*}
f(n)
&=\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n} \frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}\\
&=\frac{\ln n+\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n} \frac{\ln((n+1)!)-\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}\\
&=\biggl(1+\frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\ln n}\biggr)\biggl(1-\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}\biggr).
\end{align*}
By [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation),
$$
\ln n!=n\ln n-n+O(\ln n).
$$
Hence, we see that $\ln n!\sim n\ln n$, where $\sim$ means that the ratio of the two sides tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}
&=\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}\cdot\frac{\ln(n+1)}{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}\cdot\frac1{(n+1)}\to0
\end{align*}
as $n\to\infty$ since the first term converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$. So the sequence $f(n)$ converges to $1$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I'm really sorry if this is really rudimentary maths but how did you come up with the functions to use in the sandwich method:

$$\frac1n<\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}<\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n+\ln(n+1)}$$. 

How did you see 

$$
\frac1n<\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}
$$

and 

$$
\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln((n+1)!)}<\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln n+\ln(n+1)}

$$
I assumed it was looking at:

$$
\frac{\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+1)}}{\frac{\ln(n+1)}{\ln(n+1)} + \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n+1)} + \frac{\ln(n-1)}{\ln(n+1)}...}
$$

Comment: @SalicBlu3 I updated my answer. Let me know if something else needs clarification.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb I actually think that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n + 1)}{\ln(n) + \ln(n + 1)} = \frac{1}{2}$$

because 

$$\ln(n) + \ln(n + 1) = \ln((n + 1)^2 - n - 1) = \ln((n + 1)^2) + \ln(1 - 1/(n + 1))$$
$$ = 2\ln(n + 1) + \ln(1 - 1/(n + 1))$$
$$\implies \frac{\ln(n +1)}{\ln(n) + \ln(n + 1)} = \frac{\ln(n + 1)}{2\ln(n + 1) + \ln(1 - 1/(n+1))} \to \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: @J.Marx-Kuo Yes, you are right. Thank you very much for pointing out my mistake. I will correct my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what your textbook is going for, but I would use Stirling's approximation, which states that

$$\ln(n!) = n \ln n - n + O(\ln n)$$

check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) for reference as to what that notation means. With this, we can evaluate

$$\frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln(n)} = n \frac{\ln(n) - 1}{\ln(n)} \approx n$$
$$\frac{\ln(n + 1)}{\ln((n + 1)!)} = \ln(n + 1) \frac{1}{(n + 1)[\ln(n + 1) - 1]} \approx \frac{1}{n + 1}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) \approx \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n + 1} = 1$$

Comment: OP seems to ask for a elementary solution possibly using "sandwich" theorem and not "any other" method.

Comment: Noted, I'll try to edit my response or rewrite the solution later today.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln((n+1)!)}=\frac{\ln(n!)}{\ln(n!)+\ln(n+1)}.$$

As the factorial has $n/2$ factors larger than $n/2$, $\ln(n!)>n/2\ln(n/2)$ and the above ratio tends to$1$.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of the first factor is clearly $1$ because $$\log(n + 1) = \log n + \log(1 + 1/n)$$ and hence $$\frac{\log(n + 1)}{\log n} = 1 + \frac{\log(1 + 1/n)}{\log n} \to 1 + 0 = 1$$ as $n \to \infty$.

The second factor is $a_{n}/b_{n}$ where $a_{n} = \log n!$ and $b_{n} = \log (n + 1)!$. We can see that $b_{n} \to \infty$ monotonically and hence by [Cesaro-Stolz Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) if $(a_{n + 1} - a_{n})/(b_{n + 1} - b_{n}) \to L$ then so does $a_{n}/b_{n}$.

Now $$\frac{a_{n + 1} - a_{n}}{b_{n + 1} - b_{n}} = \frac{\log(n + 1)}{\log (n + 2)} \to 1$$ as shown for the first factor above. Hence the second factor $a_{n}/b_{n} \to 1$. And therefore the whole product tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.